# Run loom demo on IDEA

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, project-loom

I want to run loom's demo, I downloaded jdk18-loom from http://jdk.java.net/loom/, and downloaded the latest version of `IDEA`:

[image]

No matter I choose `X` or `17-preview`, the program cannot run, reports:
`Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() Is an API in a preview feature`.

How to solve it？

Comment: Hi! JDK 18 is not yet released, the support will appear only in 2022.1.

Comment: You have to add `-enablepreview` as JVM parameter to you run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do step by step.

**Update to the IDE to the latest version**

**Download a jvm with loom**

**Add the loom JDK to the IDE**

**Set it both to project and to your build tool**

**Set enable preview and source to 19 as compiler options**
to do this, got to prefs -> compiler -> java compiler, uncheck the --release option thing and add the following compiler args for specific project global

```
--enable-preview --source 19
```

these are directly passed to javac when it compiles

**Set the enable preview on you run configuration**
add `--enable-preview` as a jvm option (if you don't see it click 'Modify options')

You should be good to go, I faced a bug where sometimes gradle complained that it is not compatible with my JVM, to resovle this I had to switch the gradle VM to java 17, wati for it to build and them back to 19

Comment: For gradle users, in addition to the points mentioned above I also had to add the code mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61849770/846300

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run loom project by [JosePaumard](https://github.com/JosePaumard/Loom_demo)
There are multiple steps as of now to make it work.

1. Download suitable java version with all the feature you wanted to try.
2. If it is using any build tools, make sure it is compatible with java version you are trying.
3. build tool settings needs to be updated with JVM arguments e.g. for maven `export MAVEN_OPTS="--enable-preview --add-modules=jdk.incubator.concurrent --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED"` or in pom.xml file.
4. set JAVA_HOME to proper JAVA version
5. Intellij-Idea configs: Change JAVA_compiler configurations and each class runConfigurations
6. Change Project level `SDK version` and set `language level` to preview features you need to test.
7. Update to latest Intellij-idea IDE, verified with 2023.1 version

[Ref](https://github.com/dineshbhagat/Loom_demo)

---

Latest [Java 21](https://adoptium.net/) support for following frameworks and Kotlin

- [SpringBoot 3.2](https://start.spring.io/)
- Kotlin [1.9.20](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)(but this has issue with kapt annotation processor), so better use [1.9.21](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.9.21)
- Gradle version: [8.5](https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/release-notes.html)
- Latest intellij-idea IDE version or after 2023.1